# Ajax call returning empty response despite code behind returning correct data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm doing something like:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/Modal/getModalInfo',
    data: '{"machine":"' + machine + '"}',
    success: function (response) {
        modalData = response;
        fillModal();
    }
});
```

If I debug the C# and check the response being sent back to the JS, the data looks completely correct.

The reponse in the Ajax call is just:

```
response = Object {}
```

and completely empty. I am doing several other Ajax calls in the exact same way that are executing correctly.

Edit:

As far as what the C# is returning to Ajax:

```
        try {
            return Json(allInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return new JsonResult();
        }
```

"allinfo" looks like:

```
    AllTheInfo allInfo = new AllTheInfo();


    class AllTheInfo {
    List<DownTimes> dList;

    internal List<DownTimes> DList {
        get { return dList; }
        set { dList = value; }
    }
    List<PartsMade> pList;

    internal List<PartsMade> PList {
        get { return pList; }
        set { pList = value; }
    }

    PartsTotals pTotal;

    internal PartsTotals PTotal {
        get { return pTotal; }
        set { pTotal = value; }
    }
}
```

The classes that are referenced inside that class are other custom classes I've made.

Edit: I also modified my Ajax call to catch errors and it doesn't seem to think there are any errors, again, just an empty success response.

Edit again: I've now attempted to convert the object I'm returning to a Json string within C# using the following:

```
        string jsontext = "";
        try {
            jsontext = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allInfo);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, jsontext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

The problem now is that the call to JsonConvert is completing successfully (no error being caught) but the string is equal to "{}"

I'm not sure why this would be interpreted as successful.

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab?

Comment: Can you post to getModalInfo action code?

Comment: The function is too large and contextually irrelevant to post all of it, but I'll add some code as to what getModalInfo() is returning.

Comment: Default Json() Sucks, espicially if you have dictionaries you try using newsoft json

Comment: The problem is that's the same way I'm returning data to other Ajax calls, using Json().

Comment: when im using ajax in the data property, my syntax is like this 
`data: {'machine': machine},`

Comment: There's no concern really with the Ajax call as like I said the C# side is doing everything just fine, and the Ajax call is identical to the other ones I'm using that are working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5 different classes I'm using to create the final object I'm passing back to Ajax have getters and setters, one of the classes had their getters/setters marked like:

```
internal List<PartsMade> PList {
        get { return pList; }
        set { pList = value; }
    }
```

and should have been marked:

```
public List<PartsMade> PList {
        get { return pList; }
        set { pList = value; }
    }
```

This was causing the Json serializers in C# to be incapable of accessing the classes through their getters.

The output was correct after changing the getter's access modifier to public.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in the past when the client-side fails to parse the JSON coming back from the server due to syntax errors, additional text in the response (e.g. HTML tags etc.).  Best bet is to use something like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or similar proxy to see exactly what's coming back in the response (not just what you're returning from the C# side as there may be additional filters, modules etc. affecting the output after it leaves your server-side method).